# Matching exact names in a longer string in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a Stata dataset with the following. Each observation links to a town in Alabama, but there are other additional words added to the name variable. I'm trying to pick out the town name from this variable. Note: this is just a sample of a larger dataset with many more "additional" words, so it's not practical to simply delete these extra words.

```
num short_name_c
1   ROBERTSDALE ALA WTR SWR & ELEC
2   GULF SHORES ALA
3   DAPHNE ALA
4   FOLEY ALA
5   FAIRHOPE ALA UTILS REV
6   SUMMERDALE ALA
7   FAIRHOPE ALA
8   ORANGE BEACH ALA
10  ORANGE BEACH ALA SWR REV
11  BAY MINETTE ALA
12  ROBERTSDALE ALA
13  LOXLEY ALA
14  LOXLEY ALA UTIL REV
15  ELBERTA ALA
16  SPANISH FT ALA
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG
```

I am trying to link this to a database of all towns in Alabama - it has the town name plus a town code (no filler words). I'm currently using matchit with similmethod(token_soundex) but it returns the following for num = 17:

```
num short_name_c    town_code   town    similscore
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG    157933  DAPHNE  .5
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG    122041  LOTTIE  .5
```

It also doesn't return anything for num = 1 (even though it correctly identifies Robertsdale for num = 12).

When I switch to similmethod(token_soundex) weights(root)  score(minsimple), num = 1 is correctly identified as Robertsdale but I get the following for num = 3:

```
num short_name_c    town_code   town    similscore
3   DAPHNE ALA  157933  DAPHNE  1
3   DAPHNE ALA  2579783 DAPHNE MOBILE HOME PARK .83897456
```

And I get the following for num = 17:

```
num short_name_c    town_code   town    similscore
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG    157933  DAPHNE  1
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG    2579783 DAPHNE MOBILE HOME PARK .83897456
17  DAPHNE ALA LTD OBLIG    122041  LOTTIE  1
```

Any advice on this would be much appreciated. I imagine matchit isn't the correct function to use here, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Would deleting the string " ALA *" work here?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as mentioned above - this is a small sample. There's many more filler words so I don't want to delete them one by one.

Comment: I don't think you would need to delete them one by one. I had something like `gen city = trim(regexr(short_name_c , " ALA.*",""))` in mind. If your data has a more complicated structure, perhaps you can provide a more representative sample and desired output using `dataex`.

Comment: What I mean is ALA is the issue in this small sample but there's other filler phrases throughout the sample. I'm actually looping over states before matching cities. Other examples from other states include "CHESTERFIELD MO CTFS PARTN", "CHEYENNE WYO REV", "EAST ORANGE N J", "TRAER IOWA". So just deleting "ALA" won't help with other states. Overall, I have over 750,000 observations with up to 90,000 per state.

Comment: Yes, but you could loop the regular expression over two letter states, three letter states, and full states. That seems very doable. Another idea would be `strgroup` from SSC.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, that's a good idea and I've been thinking about it. But what about this sample: "alden vlg new york", "new york n y", "huron new york", "new york mills n y"

Comment: You can add the restriction that the removed string cannot be at the start of the original string. If you wind up with an empty string at the end of the looping, you can go back to see where the problem is happening and recode it before rerunning the loop.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, thank you! Do you know what command I would use to make sure it's not at the start of the original string?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, hmm actually I found another exception: "WEST NEW YORK N J"

Comment: "WEST NEW YORK NJ" would not work with my suggestion. One solution would be to keep track of how many times you are matching as you loop. Then look at observations that match more then once and recode them manually (or something more clever if there is a pattern) before rerunning the loop.

Comment: More ideas [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1040086-matchit-new-ado-to-merge-datasets-using-different-string-similarity-methods-i-e-fuzzy-match).